# PHP printf storing and outputting

Tags: php, printf, output

I know printf is use for outputing and sprintf is use for storing.

But in this code:

```
$str = printf('%.1f', 1.3);
echo $str;
```

Why does it output 1.33? I assume it would output 1.31.3?

Comment: **Two** decimal points? How so?

Comment: That example looks like you want `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 6):

[**printf**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) function in PHP does, in fact, two things: prints its arguments (according to the format string, sent as the first one) AND returns the length of this printed string.

Usually the value returned by `printf` is not used - but not in this case. As (by format) `printf` here had to print '1.3' string (only one digit after the decimal point), its length is 3 - so it's stored in `$str` variable and gets printed in the next statement (with `echo`). So the whole output is '1.33'.

As a sidenote, this...

```
$str = print(1.3);
echo $str;
```

... prints '1.31', as [**print**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) also does two things - prints its arguments AND returns 1.